# The Keyword Used is Not Supported (MySQL and Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, error-handling

I am creating a login form using C# and MySQL. I got stuck in SQLConnection. It says that the keyword I used is not supported.

This is my code:

```
        using (var con = new SqlConnection("host=localhost;usr=root;password=admin;db=timekeeping;"))
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM receptionist WHERE username = @username AND password = @password;";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
            var count = (long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return count > 0;
        }
```

This is the screenshot of the error message:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the correct connection string keywords for MySQL:

From [Connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql):

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find the Server I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

Please change your connection string from

```
"host=localhost;usr=root;password=admin;db=timekeeping;"
```

to

```
"Server=127.0.0.1;Database=timekeeping;Uid=root;password=admin"
```

Hopefully it will work.